# Formatting String Array efficiently in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I was working on some string formatting, and I was curious if I was doing it the most efficient way.

Assume I have a String Array:

```
String ArrayOne[] = {"/test/" , "/this/is/test" , "/that/is/" "/random/words" }
```

I want the result Array to be

```
String resultArray[] = {"test", "this_is_test" , "that_is" , "random_words" }
```

It's quite messy and brute-force-like.

```
for(char c : ArrayOne[i].toCharArray()) {
      if(c == '/'){
            occurances[i]++;
      }
   }
```

First I count the number of "/" in each String like above and then using these counts, I find the indexOf("/") for each string and add "_" accordingly.

As you can see though, it gets very messy.

Is there a more efficient way to do this besides the brute-force way I'm doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on the `replace` and `replaceAll` methods of the `String` class.  Also learn how to use a regular expression to detect the beginning or the end of a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), as follows:

```
String resultArray[] = new String[ArrayOne.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOne.length; ++i) {
    resultArray[i] = ArrayOne[i].replaceAll("^/|/$", "").replace('/', '_');
}
```

The `replaceAll` method searches the string for a match to the regex given in the first argument, and replaces each match with the text in the second argument.

Here, we use it first to remove leading and trailing slashes. We search for slashes at the start of the string (`^/`) or the end of the string (`/$`), and replace them with nothing.

Then, we replace all remaining slashes with underscores using `replace`.

Comment: did you see this "/test/" will be this "test"?

Comment: @KickButtowski And what is the problem with that?

Comment: @KickButtowski: yep, that's what the first `replaceAll` is for.

Comment: @Mac consider using `replace('/', '_')` instead of `replaceAll("/", "_")` to avoid regex engine.

Comment: @Pshemo: excellent point. Will update accordingly in a moment.

Comment: @Mac String resultArray[ArrayOne.length]; does not work ? and it looks odd please correct this so I can vote u up

Comment: @KickButtowski: sorry - been working with C++ for too long. Corrected.

Comment: @Mac +1 for your clever answer :)

Comment: @Mac one question ?here /a/b/c/, here /b/ slashes count as start / and end /?